# Ubuntu Laravel 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

file config laravel (/etc/nginx/sites-available/laravel)

```
server {
    listen 97 ;
    listen [::]:97 ;

    root /var/www/TestLaravel/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; 
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

file routes web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('haha');
});

Route::get('/test', function (){
   return "test";
});
```

when i run http://ip:97/test or http://ip:97/
result 404 Not Found

I tried the search results internet but could not change anything.
I use Php 7.3, Nginx 1.10.3, Laravel 5.7.13. 
Any suggestions, tutorials or solutions, thanks

Comment: Never seen someone try to use port 97 for this kind of stuff before. Might try port 8000 or 80 instead.

Comment: i will try it, because port 80 i used to work on another

Comment: I tried it and it does not working. The result is still 404 Not Found